# FLS and CRUD Check for Platform event and Meta Data DML

Tags: security-review, field-level-security, security-scanner

This might be a silly question, but don't want to get caught under security review.

I have three questions/confirmations related to the security review

1. FLS/CRUD Check Needed while publishing platform event?
   [image]
2. FLS/CRUD Check Needed while Deploying Metadata?
   [image]
3. FLS/CRUD Check Needed for Custom Setting `getInstance`
   [image] We have checked CRUD/FLS for custom setting when we queried

At the end of the day, we couldn't able to provide FLS/CRUD permissions for custom meta data and platform event. As long as salesforce is taking care of the dmls, do we need to check any CRUD/FLS or should we provide false positive stating these?

What would be the expert recommended solution on the above, any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: All I can say is that we don't check CRUD/FLS on Platform Events (can you even do so?!) and certainly didn't list this as a false positive, and passed our review. The same applies to our Custom Settings. For deploying metadata, we only do that during install for upgrade cases, so that doesn't count and I can't really comment.